# How to use data from a file inseted in CombiTimeTable for the rest of my dynamic model on Modelica (OpenModelica)?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to operate on data from a matrix in a text file. The data is equally spaced with tabular spaces and looks like this example:

```
#1
double table1(2,4)
2     0.1231  1.2     -3.2
23    0.64    0.999   -24.0
```

I have inserted this file in a `CombiTimeTable`, but when I want to insert another block and operate with that matrix, it doesn't recognize any array.

For example, the next block I want it to be:

```
model Mymodel
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput vector[2] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-58, 50}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {18, 88}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput matrix[2,4] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, 10}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-22, 88}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorOutput x[2,2] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {38, 66}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {68, 58}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 equation
  for i in 1:2 loop
    x[1, i] = matrix[1, i]+1;
  end for;
end Mymodel;
```

`vector` and `matrix` are inputs from a `CombiTimeTable`. This model does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your example does not show how the `CombiTimeTable` is used. If you fix that, it would be easier to help. Moreover, the input `vector` is not used and the model does not pass the check in Dymola as you do not set `x[2, ;]` .